# Writing grammar rules in SML Using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, csv, icalendar, sml

I want to write a converter for iCalendar to CSV in SML. Hence, I need to write grammar rules for it. I understand that certain rules can be written by defining them as `datatype`. To begin with, I am facing problems to write rules for Regular Expressions (terminals).

As an example, I want to write the given Regex in SML :

> label → [a-zA-Z0-9-]+

Can anybody tell me how to write this rule in SML?

**EDIT**

So far, I have declared a datatype `variables` that denotes the various variables of the grammar.

```
datatype variables = Label of String
```

I have declared a function `isLabel`. It takes as input `s` (of type `string`) and returns `Label(s)` if it satisfies the given regex (by checking if ASCII values lie in the given range) else raises exception. I gotta feeling that I have found the way to solve.

Other symbols/variables of the grammar can be defined similarly in the `datatype variables.`

Comment: @benrudgers: The question has been edited to added the details.

Comment: There is some guidance on regular expressions in SML on page 163 in [*Unix Programming with Standard ML*](http://mlton.org/References.attachments/Shipman02.pdf). It looks rather involved and I haven't dug through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Unix Programming with Standard ML](http://mlton.org/References.attachments/Shipman02.pdf) page 163+ for an example of SML/NJ's regular expression library in action.

### Steps:

Add SML/NJ Library. In the smlnj REPL use:

```
CM.make "$/regexp-lib.cm"
```

Make a regular expression Engine:

```
structure RE = RegExpFn (structure P = AwkSyntax
                         structure E = BackTrackEngine)
```

Define `label`:

```
val label = RE.compileString "[a-zA-Z0-9-]+"
```

Define a target:

```
val target = "ab9A-f"
```

Match label against target:

```
val match = StringCvt.scanString (RE.find label) target
```

Extract values from `match` according to program logic.